# JavaFX Date Picker specific format error

Tags: javafx-8, stack-trace, datapicker

I've created a Sample Application which uses JavaFX-8 Date Picker. It works fine on default pattern but on a specific pattern it throws a exception. I'm trying to convert it on 'DD-MM-YYYY' pattern on default.

Here is the Source File of the Program
Please take a look.

> DatePickerController.java

```
package javafx.datepicker;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class DatePickerController {

@FXML
private DatePicker dp;

@FXML
private Button btn;

@FXML
private TextArea ta;

public void initialize() {
    String pattern = "DD-MM-YYYY";
    dp.setPromptText(pattern);
    try {
        dp.setConverter(new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

            @Override
            public String toString(LocalDate object) {
                if (object == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                return dtf.format(object);
            }

            @Override
            public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
                if (string != null & !string.isEmpty()) {
                    return LocalDate.parse(string, dtf);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And here is Main Class

> JavaFXDatePicker.java

```
package javafx.datepicker;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXDatePicker extends Application {

public static void main(String... args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage st) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/javafx/datepicker/DatePicker.fxml"));
        Scene sc = new Scene(root);
        st.setScene(sc);
        st.setTitle("JavaFX Date Picker");
        st.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And Here is FXML File

> DatePicker.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="247.0" prefWidth="372.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="javafx.datepicker.DatePickerController">
<children>
  <DatePicker fx:id="dp" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="51.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="273.0" />
  <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="99.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="273.0" text="Click" />
  <TextArea fx:id="ta" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="133.0" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="273.0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And here is the stacktarce of the error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.time.DateTimeException: Field DayOfYear cannot be printed as the value 196 exceeds the maximum print width of 2
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2548)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1746)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1720)
at javafx.datepicker.DatePickerController$1.toString(DatePickerController.java:45)
at javafx.datepicker.DatePickerController$1.toString(DatePickerController.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.updateDisplayNode(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:424)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(DatePickerSkin.java:141)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:150)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerContent.selectDayCell(DatePickerContent.java:689)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerContent.lambda$createDayCells$174(DatePickerContent.java:731)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried almost every method to resolve this but always bad luck.

Please give me suggestions to resolve this and also explain this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the following:

String pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";